# How to use a combined index for expensive aggregating queries?

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, query-optimization

I am using the following query on a relatively large table (~20million rows):

```
SELECT 
    MAX(`col_1`) 
FROM `table` 
WHERE  
    col_2 = X AND
    col_3 = Y AND
    col_4 = Z
```

I have a combined index on the columns col_2, col_3 and col_4 and a separate one on col_1, but the query is still multiple orders of magnitude slower than the same query without the `WHERE` part.

How can I use indices to improve the performance on this?

Comment: Have you checked that the index is used at all with "Explain"? Does the index contain the columns in this exact order?

Comment: What engine are you using? MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: The engine is InnoDB. I also have an index on all 4 columns, does it have to be in that particular order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented under [How MySQL Uses Indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-indexes.html):

> MySQL uses indexes for these operations:
>
> `[ deletia ]`
>
> - To find the [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) or [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) value for a specific indexed column ***`key_col`***. This is optimized by a preprocessor that checks whether you are using `WHERE key_part_N = constant` on all key parts that occur before ***`key_col`*** in the index. In this case, MySQL does a single key lookup for each [`MIN()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_min) or [`MAX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_max) expression and replaces it with a constant. If all expressions are replaced with constants, the query returns at once. For example:
>
>   ```
>   SELECT MIN(key_part2),MAX(key_part2)
>   FROM tbl_name WHERE key_part1=10;
>   ```

Therefore, MySQL cannot use the simple index that you have defined on `col_1` for finding `MAX(col_1)` when you are applying a filter: it must instead scan all matching rows (albeit it can do this in descending order of `col_1` by sorting upon that simple index), as would be shown by the `EXPLAIN` output for your query.

You should use an index on `(col_2, col_3, col_4, col_1)`.

Comment: Thank you, this pushed the query time to the level it has without the `where`
 part

Answer (score 1):

You might try by indexing `col_1` in fourth position, but much depends on the structure of the table (i.e., weight of a single row). When calculating `MAX` on `col_1`, without `WHERE`, the information is immediately available through the index (just walk it always keeping to the left, as it were).

Adding a `WHERE`, it is no longer so. Your query might well be already optimized. Further improvements might (maybe) be done by knowing the type and distribution of X, Y and Z.

(A stupid example: say that `col_2`, `col_3` and `col_4` are known to be in the range (-255,+255). Then you could think of adding an extra denormalized column holding `(((col_1+255)*512+(col_2+255))*512+(col_3+255))` and indexing on that and `col_1`. Maybe even *clustering* based on that index. This is worthwhile if you can find an injective function with results in a reasonably small datatype, and you often run "exact" queries on X, Y and Z, i.e. no `WHERE col_2 BETWEEN X1 AND X2` stuff).

Comment: Thank your for your answer. The queries are always "exact" in my case, because col_2-4 are parameters of a function and col_1 is a timestamp created when that function ran. What I want to know is "When was the last time the function ran with these parameters".

Comment: Well, in that case, if the parameters have small enough cardinality, you might be able to construct a single integer from them. I suspected they were integer lattice coordinates; but if they're floating point, the fourfold index is the only possibility, I'm afraid. Happy to know that it was a possibility that worked :-)